# JavaScript variable images is not value expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm a complete beginner to HTML and JavaScript. I've encountered a problem. I have a button and under `onclick`, I have :

```
onclick="document.getElementById('slideCurrent').src=images[1]"
```

and in the JavaScript portion, I have :

```
var images = [
    "PATH BLABLABLA_1",
    "PATH BLABLABLA_2",
    "PATH BLABLABLA_3"
];
```

For some reason, it won't display the image. However, if I put the path directly there, it will work normally.

What I want is that the appropriate image appears based on the array index. For some reason, the console is telling me that the path is incorrect:
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Here is more complete code:

```
    <img id="slideCurrent" 
         src="file:///C:/Users/philip/Desktop/htmlCSA_files/CSA_InfoGuide_TUTORIALSLIDE1.png"
         width="500"
         height="333"/>

    <input type="image"
           id="arrowCircularRight"
           src="file:///C:/Users/philip/Desktop/htmlCSA_files/arrowCircular_right.png"
           onclick="document.getElementById('slideCurrent').src=images[1]"
           width="50" 
           height="50"/>
    <script>
    var images = [
        "file:///C:/Users/philip/Desktop/htmlCSA_files/CSA_InfoGuide_TUTORIALSLIDE1.png",
        "file:///C:/Users/philip/Desktop/htmlCSA_files/CSA_InfoGuide_TUTORIALSLIDE2.png",
        "file:///C:/Users/philip/Desktop/htmlCSA_files/CSA_InfoGuide_TUTORIALSLIDE3.png",
        "file:///C:/Users/philip/Desktop/htmlCSA_files/CSA_InfoGuide_TUTORIALSLIDE4.png",
        "file:///C:/Users/philip/Desktop/htmlCSA_files/CSA_InfoGuide_TUTORIALSLIDE5.png"
    ];

</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: Where could I find the console?

Comment: Nevermind my mistake. The consoles returns `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, Followed by `bla/bla/bla/undefined`

Comment: Chrome. I used inspect element and went to the console tab.

Comment: Then that means your path is not correct

Comment: But if I place the path directly after src instead of using the array value, it works fine.

Comment: Could you create a live example or post some markup demonstrating the problem

Comment: @Makyen Will my modification suffice?

Comment: @AndrewL. Well basically I have a button. When the button is clicked, the image under the id `currentSlide`'s src will change to the path specified under the specific array index. However, if I do `images[1]`, I get an error saying the path is invalid. But, if I place that path directly, it will display the correct image on click.

Comment: @PhilipBeckerm We want to help. It is **much** easier to help if we do not have to recreate all the code needed to test the situation ourselves. This is code that you already have, which we would have to duplicate in order to test any help we provide to you. So, please help us to help you and provide a [mcve] with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher. This *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even then, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: @Makyen Will do. Ill post my complete script.

Comment: @PhilipBecker, By [mcve] I mean enough code such that we can take exactly what you have in the question, test it out and duplicate the problem without having to add significant (if any) additional code. A good way to do this, for JavaScript/HTML/CSS questions, is to [try using a snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Snippets allow you to put all the code needed in one organized section that can be run and seen to duplicate the problem. They help quite a bit.

Comment: @Makyen Alright, I added enough code to get the gist of it.

Comment: @PhilipBecker, Thank you.  Much better. Definitely easier to test to determine what the problem was. I have retracted my close vote, removed my down vote, and voted up.

Comment: Thanks. It's nice to get help instead of just being down voted with no feedback. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your choice of variable name. The variable `images` conflicts with [`document.images`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/images). If you use a different variable name, it will work.

Below is your code (slightly modified) in a snippet.  For testing, I have changed the image URLs to ones that are valid on Stack Overflow, adjusted the size of the `<img>`, and added a line explaining what image to click.  I changed the variable name from `images` to `myImages`.

```html
<img id="slideCurrent" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy5g5.png"/>

<p>Click the image below to change the one above this line (only changes once)</p>

<input type="image"
    id="arrowCircularRight"
    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMuO.png"
    onclick="document.getElementById('slideCurrent').src=myImages[1];"
    width="50" 
    height="50"/>

<script>
    var myImages = [
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy5g5.png",
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/S33VZ.png"
    ];
</script>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help! :-)